# How many words arranged from an n-letters word have no correct position to the original one

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I would like to know how many arrangements from a 5-letters word have no correct position to the original one. 
For example, the original word is FOXES and one arrangement is OXESF.

I tried using 5! - 4! - 3! - 2! but seems like it's not the right answer.

Comment: See [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Try with inclusion-exclusion principle. Make a sets $A_i$ of arrangments where $i-$th letter is fixed for $i\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.